# Corrupted 7z file

Tags: archive, fedora, 7zip

I recently wanted to try out Fedora. So I transfered all my files to it via USB. Then I got frustrated with it, placed all my files in a 7z archive and then copied them back to the drive. Now, every time I try to open the archive, "an error occurred while loading the archive" Thanks for your help

[edit]
There is no password on the archive.

ls -alF file.7z

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 jesse jesse 2422670837 Nov  3 22:58 file.7z
```

7z t file.7z

```
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

Processing archive: jesse.7z

Error: Can not open file as archive
```

$  7z l file.7z | head -15

> 7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18 p7zip
>   Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)
>
> Error: jesse.7z: Can not open file as archive
>
> Errors: 1

Comment: Maybe pointing out the obvious, but are you sure 7z is actually installed? Although the archive manager can work with 7z files, it will only work if you install it. That isn't the case by default. So maybe your file inst corrupt at all.

Comment: Yes, I installed it right after I installed 13.10.

Comment: okay, have you tried extracting it directly with 7z instead of the archive manager?

Comment: (To do that, Using the terminal just cd to the directory where your 7z archive is located and do: 7z e YourArchiveName)

Comment: Error: Can not open file as archive

Comment: You may have to face the truth that this archive is broken and cannot be repaired. I once had a broken `.tar.gz` and was able to recover most of the contents by letting `cpio` run for a while, but that won't work on 7z. Therefore: make backups (more than 2 copies of a file) and test them!

Comment: I don't believe in irrecoverable data (except for a purposefully destroyed). It's there, it's just not built correctly. You don't throw out a castle b/c the front gate has been knocked down. You rebuild it.

Comment: @KI4JGT unless your servants have no idea how to rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two 7zip programs in the Ubuntu archives: `p7zip` and `p7zip-full`. Make sure `p7zip-full` is installed. Reboot to make double sure.

Otherwise, try copying the archive to a Windows recognized filesystem on a pen drive or something and try it on a Windows machine with 7z installed.

If the above procedures do not work, the `.7z` file is incomplete or damaged and must be redone. If you deleted your data, unfortunately, your only hope is to recover as much of the most valuable pieces as possible from the medium you got it from in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The error *"an error occurred while loading the archive"* surely means the file is corrupted. No doubt about it!

If you want to recover your data from corrupt 7z archive, you must Google some 3rd party recovery software. I can recommend you **SysInfoTools Archive Recovery** software here. Try its free demo version first to scan your corrupt 7z file. In demo version, you will come to know how much data will be recovered from the corrupt 7z file. To save the data, you need full version.

Try its free demo version first.

Answer (score 0):

I would use foremost,  if anyone in the future needs this;  its a tool you can use to recover file types, from either, a file itself. (Like a 7Z,rar, or tar file) or a whole disk.

Reply if this was useful!

Regards,

William.